# python 2.7 list , something I don't anderstand

Tags: python

I have the following python 2.7 that make me crazy, do I miss something?

```
    my_list = [ { "cluster_name": "a"},{"cluster_name": "a"},{"cluster_name": "b"}]

    ret = []
    c_list = []
    for obj in my_list:
        #ret.append(obj)
        if obj["cluster_name"] not in c_list:
            c_list.append(obj["cluster_name"])   
            ret.append({
                    'obj': obj,
                    'c_list': c_list
            })
    return ret
```

get result:

```
            "c_list": [
                "a",
                "b"      <= why b is set here?
            ],
            "obj": {
                "cluster_name": "a"
            }
        },
        {
            "c_list": [
                "a",
                "b"
            ],
            "obj": {
                "cluster_name": "b"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Thanks for your answer?
more details
more details
more details
more detailsmore detailsmore details

Comment: indeed my version is 2.7.5. It does not change anything to the question

Comment: Because "cluster name":b is in your list?

Comment: There is only ONE variable c_list.  Just because you append it to another data structure doesn't mean you "freeze" it in its present state.  It's still a list and you can still modify it later in your code.  When you print it, you will see its content at the point when you print it; so if you print it once at the end you will see its final value and not its intermediate ones.  Maurice Mayer's answer is correct but you should understand why it works.  It works this way in all Python versions (and every other language I know of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a 'copy' of `c_list`

```
my_list = [ { "cluster_name": "a"},{"cluster_name": "a"},{"cluster_name": "b"}]

ret = []
c_list = []
for obj in my_list:
    #ret.append(obj)

    if obj["cluster_name"] not in c_list:
        c_list.append(obj["cluster_name"])   
        ret.append({
                'obj': obj,
                'c_list': [x for x in c_list]  # create copy!
        })
print(ret)
```

Output:

```
[{'c_list': ['a'], 'obj': {'cluster_name': 'a'}},
 {'c_list': ['a', 'b'], 'obj': {'cluster_name': 'b'}}]
```

Comment: amazing! for my purpose, if obj["cluster_name"] not in [x for x in c_list]  works.   It s weird isn't it?